# Create Partition

Tags: banco-de-dados, sql-server, sql-server-2012, tsql

Estou particionando uma tabela na minha base, criei a function partition e o scheme partition. Mas quando vou no *Create partition Wizard* o Radiobutton *Existing partition function* fica desabilitado mesmo com function criada. Acontece a mesma coisa para o schema.

Alguém me ajuda?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]